# URLSession data task returns nil response - 404 page not found

Tags: ios, swift4, nsurlsession

I'm trying to invoke an https request using `URlSession` in Swift 4. I don't get an error but I receive a nil response.

I have tried with adding ATS in plist. Added TLS version, NSIncludesSubdomains keys etc. Still does'nt work. Not sure what might be the issue. Any help?

Below is my code :

```
 url = URL(string: "https://quickweb.support.qvalent.com/OnlinePaymentServlet3")

 let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!, method: method, body: data.toEncodedData(), cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy)
            let useMainThread = true
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            var queue: OperationQueue? = nil
            if useMainThread {
                queue = OperationQueue.main
            }


let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: queue)



 urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest){ data, resonse, error in
        if let error = error {
            self.errorMessage += Constants.shared.dataErrorMsg+error.localizedDescription
            onComplete(false,nil,self.errorMessage)
        }else if let data = data{
            self.parse(data: data, with: onComplete)
        }


 }.resume()
```

Surprisingly, I have the same call done in Objective C years back which works absolutely fine.Trying to convert it to swift 4 in Xcode 9.3 fails.

When I print the response data it says "404 page not found"

Comment: As far as i understand problem is with your body, may be body data is not rightly formatted which is expected in server side.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kazi. But there cannot be an issue with body since I have taken the body from the swift code and hardcoded it in the Objective - C code to test and it works perfectly there.

Comment: My assumption is something with the url that is blocking. It's a payment gateway url. I am very sure parameters sent through POST are perfect since the same works in old project done in Obj C

Comment: try to put a `/` at the end of your `URL` string. i faced such problem where my backend was django

Comment: Just tried that. still response is nil and page not found error. looks like it has something to do with plist configuration. Like I mentioned in the post already tried with ATS and adding other bool values. Am I missing something to add in plist for this?

Comment: In the old Obj C project, App Transport Security Settings isn't added and this works fine. Here, in latest swift 4 and Xcode 9.3, whether you add or not this api call doesn't work. Rest all the API calls work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. It was nothing to do with the request or url. Client was expecting a delegate call which was in place but not getting called and hence it was returning 404. URLSessionTaskDelegate was the key.